# jquery text() from two classes

Tags: javascript, jquery

**HTML**

```
<div class="a">1
<input type="button" value="send" class="b">
</div>
<div class="a">2
<input type="button" value="send" class="b">
</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(".b").click(function () {           
    var b=$(".a").text();
    alert(b);
});
```

On pressing first button I want only 1 and on pressing second button I want only 2
http://jsfiddle.net/4n6ou0ka/1/

Comment: `$(this).closest('.a').text();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(".b").click(function () {           
    alert($(this).parent().text());
    // or
    alert($(this).closest('.a').text());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `this.parent`

```
$(".b").click(function () {
  var b=$(this).parent().text();
  alert(b);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/4n6ou0ka/3/

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is to use the `this` keyword as a search reference so you can get only `this`'s parent with the "a" class.

Check this modified version of your sample: http://jsfiddle.net/6qhun7hz/

Answer (score 0):

All-in-one !

```
$(this).parent().text();
```

Or

```
$(this.parentNode).text();
```

Or

```
$(this).closest('.a').text();
```

Or

```
this.parentNode.firstChild.textContent
```